# Windows Phone 7 pivot control keeps changing pivot items after many quick swipes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a pivot control WP7 app with 3 pivot items.  The issue I've seen is if you swipe the app quickly many times in a row (say, 10 times or more), the pivots keep cycling through.

Is there any way I can detect that I'm in the middle of swiping and not process the current swipe?

Answer (score 0):

That's a "feature" from the Windows Phone OS. Any application with a Pivot does this.

To override this you'll probably have to write a custom control based on Pivot and make it ignore flick gestures while it's changing view.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the built-in WP7 apps don't exhibit this behavior, so I wonder how or what they're using to get around it.

Comment: Hmm, that actually true. But does the feature ruin your app? Or is it something you happened to come upon, but doesn't really affect the overall UX?

Comment: No, it doesn't ruin the app, it's just polish.

Comment: I haven't even noticed this before you mentioned it, but it shouldn't ruin the UX as long you don't give the user reason to flip through the pivots that fast :)